# / directory for git bash on windows

Tags: windows, bash, directory, git-bash

So I've recently moved from a macOS terminal to git bash for Windows and I'm confused by what git bash is showing as my root directory or specifically the directory at `/`.

All of my data is stored in my `/c/` directory at `/c/Users/myUSER`. And that's fine with me.

Now when I, `$ cd /` and subsequently `$ ls`, I see all of the below folders that I was used to on my Mac, but `/c/` is not visible!

```
myUSER /
$ ls
bin/  etc/           LICENSE.txt  ReleaseNotes.html  unins000.exe*
cmd/  git-bash.exe*  mingw64/     tmp/               unins000.msg
dev/  git-cmd.exe*   proc/        unins000.dat       usr/
```

And now I am very surprised I can do the following:

```
myUSER /
$ cd c
myUSER c
$
```

Can someone please explain this behavior?

Comment: It's clear that the available DOS drives a-z are made available virtually in the root directory. Also, these names are reserved. For example, if we try to create a directory using a letter for a non-assigned DOS drive, it fails with `ENOENT`, file not found. It's not clear why they don't include the available drives when listing the root directory.

Comment: They're listed in the output of the `mount` command or via `cat /proc/mounts`.

Answer (score 1):

This originally comes from MSYS2, as described in [git-for-windows/git issue 111](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/111):

> The post-install scripts that are part of [the filesystem package](https://github.com/git-for-windows/MSYS2-packages/tree/master/filesystem) are not included in the release builds. Three of them are useful:
>
> - [`01-devices.post`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/MSYS2-packages/blob/master/filesystem/01-devices.post) sets up various folders and symlinks inside /dev, notably including /dev/fd, which is required for Bash process substitution to work.
> - [`03-mtab.post`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/MSYS2-packages/blob/master/filesystem/03-mtab.post) creates `/etc/mtab` as a symlink to `/proc/mounts`.

(that is where the drives are listed/available)

> - [`06-windows-files.post`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/MSYS2-packages/blob/master/filesystem/06-windows-files.post) creates the hosts, protocols, services, and networks files in `/etc` by copying them from `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc`.
>
> As a side note, the symlinks it creates are not true symlinks but [Cygwin's fancy pseudo-symlinks](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#pathnames-symlinks), so creating them does not require admin privileges.

Comment: To clarify, my /etc, /dev, and /proc are currently populated, so perhaps the above scripts have already been executed.  Is there any further configuration that is necessary for my git bash to behave properly?

Comment: @macavich normally, no: my answer was to point out why the drives are mounted (part of a series of script which will make /proc/mounts available)